# PHP Parse Error!

Tags: php, string, text, escaping

I'm trying to figure out where this error comes in (I'm trying to output some HTML using PHP).

```
$newLI = "<li id = $row['\"id\"'] style=\"padding-right: 20px; display:inline; border-right: 1px gray solid; margin: 0px; color: white;\">";
```

Which ends up giving me:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in /homepages/31/d346239161/htdocs/Bloominate/alpha/getProfileData.php on line 23
```

I can't figure out where the parse error is :(.

Comment: .. i love as well as hate stackoverflow when 5 answers have come while I was writing mine :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to enclose $row['id'] in curly braces, like `{$row['id']}`
No other escaping is necessary on it, though it should be enclosed in single quotes for the HTML attribute: `id='{$row['id']}'`

So a complete answer using no string contatenation and double-quoting would be:

```
$newLI = "<li id='{$row['id']}' style='padding-right: 20px; display:inline; border-right: 1px gray solid; margin: 0px; color: white;'>";
```

Answer (score 5):

It may be easier to avoid these errors by using single quotes and string concatenation:

```
$newLI = '<li id="'.$row['id'].'" style="padding-right: 20px; display:inline; border-right: 1px gray solid; margin: 0px; color: white;">';
```

Additionally you don't have to escape double quotes of the HTML code.

Answer (score 2):

your problem is with $row itself.

```
// The following is okay, as it's inside a string. Constants are not looked for
// within strings, so no E_NOTICE occurs here
print "Hello $arr[fruit]";      // Hello apple

// With one exception: braces surrounding arrays within strings allows constants
/    / to be interpreted
print "Hello {$arr[fruit]}";    // Hello carrot
print "Hello {$arr['fruit']}";  // Hello apple

// This will not work, and will result in a parse error, such as:
// Parse error: parse error, expecting T_STRING' or T_VARIABLE' or T_NUM_STRING'
// This of course applies to using superglobals in strings as well
print "Hello $arr['fruit']";
print "Hello $_GET['foo']";

// Concatenation is another option
print "Hello " . $arr['fruit']; // Hello apple
```

see http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php for more info.

Answer (score 1):

The actual answer will be :-

```
$newLI = '<li id = '.$row['id'].' style="padding-right: 20px; display:inline; border-right: 1px gray solid; margin: 0px; color: white;">';
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
$newLI = "<li id = $row['\"id\"'] style=\"padding-right: 20px; display:inline; border-right: 1px gray solid; margin: 0px; color: white;\">"
```

To:

```
$rowID = $row['id'];
$newLI = "<li id=$rowID style=\"padding-right: 20px; display:inline; border-right: 1px gray solid; margin: 0px; color: white;\">"
```

It's because you reference $row['id'].

Answer (score 0):

Why not keep it clean and simple like:

```
<?php

$newLI = "<li id =".$row['id']." style=\"padding-right: 20px; display:inline; border-right: 1px gray solid; margin: 0px; color: white;\">";

?>
```

Answer (score -2):

try this

```
$newLI = "<li id = $row['id'] style='padding-right: 20px; display:inline; border-right: 1px gray solid; margin: 0px; color: white;'>";
```

Comment: -1 $row['id'] will not expand correctly inside double quotes.

Comment: This won't fix anything. This will give you the same parse error.

Comment: i use this all the time and it works correctly

Comment: @MBAsfoor: No you don't. You probably write `$newLI = "<li id='$row[id]' ...>";` if anything.

Comment: You're right, my apologies. Braces are needed for object properties but not array keys.